# Desktop black outs when changing to folder view [KDE]

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

I'm trying to set the desktop layout to "Folder View". I set the desktop to use plain color. As soon as I hit Apply, the desktop reflects the selected color and then, blacks out. The desktop becomes unresponsive to mouse clicks  while the rest of the desktop environment works fine.

[image: Information about KDE I'm using]

[image: Information about Ubuntu I'm using]

Here is a gif reproducing the bug
[image]